# Coda, segno; How to repeat chorus 3 times?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, musical-forms, guitar-pro, repeats

I have a song in this form:

bar 1 = a
bar 2 = b
bar 3 = chorus
bar 4 = d
bar 5 = e
bar 6 = chorus
bar 7 = g
bar 8 = h
bar 9 = chorus

Do I need rewrite "chorus" every time? Or can I use some repetition effect like:

bar 1 = a
bar 2 = b
bar 3 = chorus **
bar 4 = d
bar 5 = e **
bar 6 = g
bar 7 = h **

??

Which one is musically correct?

I tried "Dal Segno Al Coda"-> "Segno" (chorus)-> "to coda" -> "Coda"

This works perfectly for the first repetition, but I can't use it for the second. (I'm using Guitar pro 5, but that shouldn't matter.)

Comment: Since it's a computer program, can't you just copy / paste the material?

Comment: @jjmusicnotes yes, I can..but my goal is to register the music, so I don't know if it is okay to copy and paste, or is there a better way (correct way)

Comment: Related question: [Is there a definitive notation for multiple repeats?](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/116391/70803).

Answer (score 3):

By what you explain, it sounds like you want to repeat a section 3 times.

You don't need to use a Coda and Segno because a closing repet can be used more than twice as seen in the [Guitar Pro manual](http://download3.guitar-pro.com/ba939e95a1bfa0a7168bf410c0b994a4/559f7eaa/gp6/GP6%20Users%20Manual%20EN.pdf):

> **Repeat close**
>
> This symbol replaces a closing bar-line, and sends you
>   back to the last Repeat open sign. A dialog window will open up for
>   you to indicate the number of repeats you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need the playback to be like you ask, you could use repetition and alternate endings.
[image: Those buttons]

It will work "playback-wise" but I doubt this is a proper use of that in music notation.

But I think this does what you want :

[image: GP repetition demo]

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I could not to use it though, because there are some others repetitions between chorus and verses (the song has actually 50 bars). Playback is not important. I have decided to rewrite! But it was interesting.. thank you!

Comment: If the structure can be clearly notated using repeats and 1x, 2x etc ending brackets, don't be afraid to use them.  And "to coda 3rd x" is perfectly acceptable.
If in danger of getting unclear and complicated, write it all out.

Answer (score 2):

D.S. al Coda is on the right track. Here is my recommendation:

[image: Roadmap for repeated jumps to chorus]

#### OR

[image: Alternative to volta endings]

The chorus would be written separately from the rest of the tune — in the way a coda can be — with three endings: one returning to "d", one returning to "g", and one ending the song. The endings could be done using voltas or, since each chorus is identical, just with written instructions. Also, *al fine* could be added to the final "To C" for additional clarity for the reader. In the body of the song, just include a "to chorus" indication at the appropriate locations.

Answer (score 1):

Write "3 verses" or "Play 3 times" over the repeated section.  At the To Coda sign write "To Coda after 3rd verse".   That's understandable for a live player.

If you want playback from your computer program you may have to be more ingenious.  How far is the To Coda jump from the End Repeat barline?  Is a 1,2 ending bracket and a 3 ending one feasible?

If ONLY playback matters, just write the whole thing out!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an image with a solution:

[image: Repeat_Chorus]

This solution will play

a, b then Chorus followed by 1st ending with d and e,

then repeat Chorus followed by the 2nd ending with g and h,

then repeat the Chorus and end.

But apart from that I will say that is rather simple to actually write the whole thing out instead, rewriting the Chorus, because it is easy to rewrite it with copy and paste and it is easier to read for the musician without all this going back and fourth.