# What is the notation for repeating 3 times in keyboard sheet music?

Tags: notation, repeats

In sheet music how do you notate repetition of a measure 3 times? Do you put 3 above the repeat sign? For example:

[image: two measure with the second placed within repeat signs]

Comment: Note: I previously answered this question, but after finding the duplicate, I've moved my answer there: https://music.stackexchange.com/a/116391/70803