# How can I notate multiple repeats?

Tags: notation, repeats, musescore

I'm currently using MuseScore for transcribing my drum notation and it's working great - except I can't seem to find a repeat for a section to repeat more than once.

How can I notate multiple repeats?

Comment: In Musescore you can click on the measure with the last measure to be repeated (the one closed with :| mark), select "Measure Properties" and increase play count. See also https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/74084/is-there-a-definitive-notation-for-multiple-repeats However software recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To repeat multiple times in MuseScore<sup>1</sup>:

1. Right click on the measure containing the end-repeat sign and select "Measure properties...".<sup>2</sup>

[image: Measure context menu with "Measure properties..." at the bottom]

2. In the Measure Properties dialog box, set the Play Count property to the number of times the measure should be played (the repeat itself will still return to the designated starting point).

[image: Measure Properties dialog box]

3. Click the OK button, and you're done.

---

<sup>1</sup>MuseScore version (64-bit): 3.6.2.548020600, revision: github-musescore-musescore-3224f34. This solution has been verified on Mac (MuseScore v. 3.6) and Windows (MuseScore v. 3.5).

<sup>2</sup>It is imperative that the measure containing the end-repeat sign be the one selected. When selecting any other measure, the "Play count" option does not appear in the "Measure Properties" dialog box. See step 2.

Comment: Hey @Aaron, thanks for the awesome explanation (and version inclusion!)
I wonder if it's a windows issue because I've just got `Barline` options.
I'm on Win 10 on MuseScore version (64-bit): 3.6.2.548021803, revision: github-musescore-musescore-3224f34 which makes no sense :D

Comment: @Nita Hmm.... If you select the measure, rather than right-clicking, do any of the regular menus have a "measure properties" command?

Comment: Hey @Aaron, doesn't seem so. I checked the Inspector and just for kicks checked all the viewable menus ;P Even https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/repeats-and-jumps says I'm supposed to see the Play count like you've explained above.

Comment: @Nita No promises, but I'll see if I can try it out on a Windows computer tomorrow.

Comment: @Nita I was finally able to double-check how things work on Windows, and on my system it works as described above. The essential detail is that the selected measure must contain the end-repeat sign. If any other measure is selected, the "Play count" option does not appear in the "Measure Properties" dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

Aaron’s answer addresses how you can playback multiple repeats, but not actually how you engrave it. Note that there is not a clear standard for how to specify multiple repeats, also consider this discussion: [Is there a definitive notation for multiple repeats?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/74084/is-there-a-definitive-notation-for-multiple-repeats)

If you have something in mind like displaying a `...x` above the repeat bar line you will be out of luck, MuseScore does not support that. While it is possible to balance Articulations on top of bar lines (I think mainly for the sake for fermatas) you cannot do the same for arbitrary text. It is a feature that could easily be implemented, even as a tickable property of bar lines. So the only chance is to create a text and manually balance it on top of the bar, hoping the layout does not change.

But then, as stated in the answers to the linked question this is a rather sloppy and ambiguous way of specifying such a thing anyway. Other options include the use of Volta brackets or adding a Text *Play n times* at the start of the repeat.

Comment: If you use a Rehearsal mark from the Text Palette, you can (with the Inspector) set the style as "Repeat Text Right" for text at the end of the repeat.  This works great, _unless_ if it's at the end of a line, which is a shame.

Or, you can put text at the start of the repeat with "Repeat Text Left", but that's a lot larger by default (for some reason).